# How to pass arguments with ShellExecuteEx?

Tags: winapi, ipc, shared-memory

I am using IPC for shared memory.

I need to turn on another program with IPC, but I want to know how to pass arguments.

Below is a execute function for my IPC class.

```
int execute(std::string exePath, std::string exeName, int console = 1)
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOA p_info;

    ZeroMemory(&p_info, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOA)); //초기화
    p_info.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOA);
    p_info.lpFile = exeName.c_str(); // 파일 이름
    p_info.lpDirectory = exePath.c_str(); //파일 위치

    p_info.nShow = console; //콘솔 show
    p_info.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

    return ShellExecuteEx(&p_info);
};
```

Comment: you can use `lpParameters` member or `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`, however if you not need elevation - much better use `Createprocess` instead `ShellExecuteEx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are passed using the `lpParameters` member of `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`.

Some other comments:

- Since you are explicitly using the ANSI version of the struct, `SHELLEXECUTEINFOA`, it would be appropriate to do the same for the function call and use `ShellExecuteExA`.
- Avoid the call to `ZeroMemory` by initialising the struct as part of the declaration: `SHELLEXECUTEINFOA p_info = { 0 };`
- You use `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` but then fail to close the process handle. This is a handle leak.
- Unless you use `ShellExecuteEx` with the `runas` verb to elevate the process, it would seem more appropriate to call `CreateProcess`. Why ask `ShellExecuteEx` to call `CreateProcess` when you can do so directly?